# Setting a property in prepareForSegue using a popover

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ViewController that has a couple of buttons on it created in Interface Builder. The first button will display a popover linked up in IB, it is linked to a UINavigationController and has a TableView under it with a class of `PopupViewController`.

The second button, I have an action setup for `goToCategory` and when clicking on that, I want to set a property on the `PopupViewController`

```
ViewController.m
//go to category
-(IBAction)goToCategory:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"GO TO CAT");
    //PopupViewController *popupVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popoverVC"];
    //popupVC.currentLevel = 1;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"popoverSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"seg1");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"popoverSegue"]){
        //PopupViewController *popupVC = (PopupViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] visibleViewController];
        //PopupViewController *popupVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        PopupViewController *popupVC=[[[segue destinationViewController]viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        popupVC.test = @"just a test";
        NSLog(@"seg2");
    }
}

PopupViewController.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *test;

PopupViewController.m
@synthesize test;
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSLog(@"test: %@", test); //returns test: (null)
}
```

I've found a lot of answers on SO, hence some of the commented out lines in my prepareForSegue. But none of these set the value of `test`. `PopupViewController *popupVC = [segue destinationViewController];` throws an error due to it referring to the UINavigationController so I can't use that as it is, even though that seems to be the way to do it in a lot of answers I've seen. But no matter which way I try doing it, the output is always null?

**UPDATE:**

`PopupViewController *popupVC = (PopupViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] visibleViewController];` and `PopupViewController *popupVC=[[[segue destinationViewController]viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];` from my `prepareForSegue` above both work on the 6.1 simulator. My iPad's iOS is 5.1.1 which it isn't working on. Is there something different I need to do for iOS 5?

Comment: Uhm, if you want to access your Popover, this should work:[(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue popoverController]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"seg1");
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"popoverSegue"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        PopupViewController *popupVC = [navController topViewController];
        popupVC.test = @"just a test";
        NSLog(@"seg2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try it writing it that way you just did, but as I mentioned, it throws an error, namely `[UINavigationController setTest:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` because the destination view controller is a UINavigationController, not the PopupViewController

Comment: Just tried your new updated code but still no luck :( Tried changing your line to `PopupViewController *popupVC = (PopupViewController *)[navController topViewController];` as well as xcode gave me a warning, 'Incompatible pointer types initializing PopupViewController __strong with an expression of type UIViewController`

Comment: Are you having two navigation controller ? Is PopupViewController set as root viewcontroller for navigation controller?

Comment: For the popover, I have one navigation controller, and yes PopupVC is set as root view controller for the navigation controller. Funnily enough though, as I was about to update my answer, `PopupViewController *popupVC = (PopupViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] visibleViewController];` and `PopupViewController *popupVC=[[[segue destinationViewController]viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];` from my original question, both seem to work on the 6.1 simulator. My iPad's iOS is 5.1.1 which it isn't working on. Is there something different I need to do for iOS 5?